# AWSCognito User getDetailHandler API not working in some particular Android devices

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

Hi we are working on AWSCognito login for Android. In that, User getDetailHandler API was not working in some of the android devices(Noted in Samsung Tab Version 4.4.4 and MotoG3 V6.0.1 APILevel 23). Seems it works fine in MiPad Version 4.4.4 and and MotoG2 Version 5.1 APILevel 22. Actually it works fine some 10 days back in all devices. Please let us know what is the problem actually and it would be helpful for us.

Comment: AppHelper.getPool().getUser(AppHelper.getCurrUser()).getDetailsInBackground(detailsHandler);


 GetDetailsHandler detailsHandler = new GetDetailsHandler() {
        public void onSuccess(CognitoUserDetails cognitoUserDetails) {

            // Store details in the AppHandler
         
        }
        public void onFailure(Exception exception) {
               
        }
    };

Comment: have you got any solution for same? I am also facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, actually the device date was wrong so far that API was not working for me. I set my device date properly and it works fine that's it.